# Dynamically colored bar charts in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

Without choosing the color explicitly like [Different coloured bars in gnuplot bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082159/different-coloured-bars-in-gnuplot-bar-chart) is there a way for GNU plot to choose some distinguished colors based on the key (like a hash?)?

[image: bars with same color]

```
# git rev-list --count master
$commits << EOD
gecko 716280
webkit 226748
blink 906439
EOD

set terminal png
set yrange [0:*]      # start at zero, find max from the data
set boxwidth 0.5      # use a fixed width for boxes
unset key             # turn off all titles
set style fill solid  # solid color boxes
set title 'commits'
plot '$commits' using 2:xtic(1) with boxes
```

Bonus: Instead of 1x10^6 (which I find odd), could it simple say 716k, 227k, 906k. I.e. the scale is in the 1000s for the Y axis.

Comment: See `help format specifier`.  The command `set ytics format "%.0s%c"` will generate labels 100k 200k 300k ... 1M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided in [Different coloured bars in gnuplot bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082159/different-coloured-bars-in-gnuplot-bar-chart) works also without defining the linetypes. Gnuplot will use the default ones.

```
set yrange [0:*]      # start at zero, find max from the data
set boxwidth 0.5      # use a fixed width for boxes
unset key             # turn off all titles
set style fill solid  # solid color boxes
set title 'commits'
plot '$commits' using 0:2:($0+1):xtic(1) with boxes lc variable
```

[image]

You can also use one of the other predefined sequences of colors adding the following line:

```
set colors {default|classic|podo}
```

Comment: Thank you. So it would appear `lc variable` is the magic I was after.

Comment: I have another question upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62828141/gnuplot-multi-column-plot-using-csv-headings

Comment: Can you explain `0:2:($0+1)` btw please?

Comment: The last column in the using specifier is required by 'lc variable' and it identifies the linetype index used to plot each row. Each linetype has its own color associated. $0 is the row number and it is here used to specify the index.