# Gnuplot multi column plot using CSV headings

Tags: gnuplot

[image: gnuplot via a Jupyter Notebook]

I'm struggling to get a multi-column bar chart / histogram going with my input as a CSV with headings. As well as the key showing the {wcfiles,wclines,clocfiles,cloclines} attributes.

```
$summary << EOD
browser,wcfiles,wclines,clocfiles,cloclines
webkitgtk-2.28.2,19472,4710385,18620,3120740
firefox-78.0.1,289298,43627834,240137,24371602
chromium-83.0.4103.116,420343,100340817,269434,49597826
EOD
set datafile separator ','
set yrange [0:*]      # start at zero, find max from the data
set style fill solid border -1
set ytics format "%.0s%c" #  will generate labels 100k 200k 300k ... 1M
set title 'sloc the Web'
plot '$summary' using 0:2:($0+1):xtic(1) with boxes lc variable,\
   "" u 3 title "wclines",\
   "" u 4 title "clocfiles"
```

Comment: I suggest looking at the histograms demo for ideas: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/histograms.html

Comment: immigration.dat is missing from that page

Comment: All of the demos and associated data are part of the gnuplot distribution, although I don't know exactly where they may have been installed on your system.  The point is that it's a csv file with the country names as column headers and the years in the ffirst column of each row.  The demo shows what commands are used to place the column headers and the row labels.

Comment: source for file 'immigration.dat': https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main/ci/master/tree/demo/immigration.dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the examples @Ethan mentioned.
In your case you should `set logscale y`, otherwise it will be difficult to visualize values with differences of several orders of magnitude.

**Code:**

```
### histogram clustered
reset session

$Data <<EOD
browser,wcfiles,wclines,clocfiles,cloclines
webkitgtk-2.28.2,19472,4710385,18620,3120740
firefox-78.0.1,289298,43627834,240137,24371602
chromium-83.0.4103.116,420343,100340817,269434,49597826
EOD

set datafile separator ','
set title 'sloc the Web'

set yrange [1000:*]
set logscale y
set ytics format "%.0s%c"

set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.9

plot $Data u 2:xtic(1) ti col,\
     '' u 3 ti col,\
     '' u 4 ti col
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]