# Gnuplot combing multiple value types in one line graph with different colours and dashes

Tags: gnuplot

[image: Three charts]

I have three different lines, where colours and their dashes means different things which I want on one plot, instead of three. How do I accomplish that?

```
set datafile separator comma
$sample <<EOD
2020-01-01,4,UK,Business
2020-02-01,4,UK,Business
2020-01-01,4,UK,Social
2020-02-01,15,UK,Social
2020-01-01,1,USA,Social
2020-02-01,25,USA,Social
EOD

set format x '%Y'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
plot '$sample' u 1:2 title "UK/Business" with linespoints dt 3 lw 5 pt 7 lc "red"
```

- `plot '$sample' u 1:2 title "USA/Social" with linespoints dt 3 lw 1 pt 7 lc "blue"`
- `plot '$sample' u 1:2 title "UK/Social" with linespoints dt 3 lw 5 pt 7 lc "blue"`

E.g. blue is "Social" and lw 1 (fine dots) is for USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the manual or `help plot`. Plot elements for the same plot are separated by comma.

> Syntax:
>
> ```
>   plot {<ranges>} <plot-element> {, <plot-element>, <plot-element>}
> ```

To improve readability you can split long code lines into several lines by using `\`. Note that no character is allowed after `\` in the same line except carriage return/line feed.

Try this:

```
plot '$sample' u 1:2 title "UK/Business" w lp dt 3 lw 5 pt 7 lc "red", \
     '' u 1:2 title "USA/Social" w lp dt 3 lw 1 pt 7 lc "blue", \
     '' u 1:2 title "UK/Social" w lp dt 3 lw 5 pt 7 lc "blue"
```

**Addition:** (a filter depending on two (string)-columns)

You can implement a filter by using the ternary operator. Check `help ternary` and `help strcol`. A value which does not pass the filter will be set to `NaN`. If you still want to your points being connected with lines, you need to `set datafile missing NaN`.

**Code:**

```
### filtered data with different line colors
reset session
set datafile separator comma

$sample <<EOD
2020-01-01,4,UK,Business
2020-02-01,4,UK,Business
2020-01-01,4,UK,Social
2020-02-01,15,UK,Social
2020-01-01,1,USA,Social
2020-02-01,25,USA,Social
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x '%d.%m.%Y' timedate
set key top left
set datafile missing NaN

myFilter(colData,colFilter1,key1,colFilter2,key2) = (strcol(colFilter1) eq key1) && (strcol(colFilter2) eq key2) ?  column(colData) : NaN

plot $sample u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(myFilter(2,3,"UK",4,"Business")) w lp dt 3 lw 5 pt 7 lc "red" title "UK/Business", \
     '' u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(myFilter(2,3,"USA",4,"Social")) w lp dt 3 lw 1 pt 7 lc "blue" title "USA/Social" , \
     '' u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(myFilter(2,3,"UK",4,"Social")) w lp dt 3 lw 5 pt 7 lc "blue" title "UK/Social"
### end of code
```

or a bit shortened if the columns 2,3,4 do not change within the plot command...

```
...
...
myTime(col) = timecolumn(col,myTimeFmt)
myFilter(key1,key2) = (strcol(3) eq key1) && (strcol(4) eq key2) ?  column(2) : NaN

plot $sample u (myTime(1)):(myFilter("UK","Business")) w lp dt 3 lw 5 pt 7 lc "red" title "UK/Business", \
     '' u (myTime(1)):(myFilter("USA","Social")) w lp dt 3 lw 1 pt 7 lc "blue" title "USA/Social" , \
     '' u (myTime(1)):(myFilter("UK","Social")) w lp dt 3 lw 5 pt 7 lc "blue" title "UK/Social"
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I understand you want the 3 lines in one plot. But not sure whether you also want to separate/filter by keyword?

Comment: yes, I want only "Social" to be blue, and only fine dots for USA. I need some sort of filter. Only if matches this string, plot with these colors. https://s.natalian.org/2020-08-25/not-what-i-want.png

Comment: I wonder if the line color and dots can be done with `lc variable` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823958/4534

Comment: yes of course. check `help points`. You can have `ps var pt var lc var` (pointsize, pointtype, linecolor) as variable. As far as I know, you cannot have this with linewidth (`lw`) and dashtype (`dt`). But maybe you can do something with linestyle (`ls`) or linetype (`lt`). Check help for these keywords.